# grails & neuroph: neural net file saving

Tags: grails, artificial-intelligence, notserializableexception

I have a project based on neuroph. Since I am computing some values in memory I wanted to save the neural net in a file through to:

```
neuralNet.save("/tmp/someprettyname.nnet")
```

where neuralNet is:

```
neuralNet = new MultiLayerPerceptron(TransferFunctionType.SIGMOID, 17, 16, 1)
```

however I get a `NotSerializableException` when saving neuralNet
I think it is related to :
https://sourceforge.net/p/neuroph/discussion/862858/thread/5bb3aa8d/?limit=25#4d19
since grails uses log4j (and maybe underneath sl4j)
any ideas welcome!!

Cheers

Jean-Marc